# org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: NOT_INSTANCE_OF: Can't create InstanceId for EntityType

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster, javers

I got this error when using Javers in Jhipster. I used the configuration for Spring boot:

```
javers:
  mappingStyle: FIELD
  algorithm: SIMPLE
  commitIdGenerator: synchronized_sequence
  prettyPrint: true
  typeSafeValues: false
  newObjectSnapshot: false
  packagesToScan:
  auditableAspectEnabled: true
  springDataAuditableRepositoryAspectEnabled: true
  sqlSchema:
  sqlSchemaManagementEnabled: true
  sqlGlobalIdCacheDisabled: false
  objectAccessHook: org.javers.hibernate.integration.HibernateUnproxyObjectAccessHook
  prettyPrintDateFormats:
    localDateTime: 'dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss'
    zonedDateTime: 'dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ssZ'
    localDate: 'dd MMM yyyy'
    localTime: 'HH:mm:ss'
```

```
public Object getIdOf(Object instance) {
        Validate.argumentIsNotNull(instance);
        if (!this.isInstance(instance)) {
            throw new JaversException(JaversExceptionCode.NOT_INSTANCE_OF, new Object[]{this.getName(), this.getBaseJavaClass().getName(), instance.getClass().getName()});
        } else if (this.hasCompositeId()) {
            Map compositeId = Collections.unmodifiableMap((Map)this.idProperties.stream().filter((p) -> {
                return p.get(instance) != null;
            }).collect(Collectors.toMap((p) -> {
                return p.getName();
            }, (p) -> {
                return p.get(instance);
            })));
            if (compositeId.isEmpty()) {
                throw new JaversException(JaversExceptionCode.ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_COMPOSITE_ID, new Object[]{this.getName(), this.getIdPropertyNames()});
            } else {
                return Collections.unmodifiableMap(compositeId);
            }
        } else {
            Object cdoId = this.getIdProperty().get(instance);
            if (cdoId == null) {
                throw new JaversException(JaversExceptionCode.ENTITY_INSTANCE_WITH_NULL_ID, new Object[]{this.getName(), this.getIdProperty().getName()});
            } else {
                return cdoId;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
public boolean isInstance(Object cdo) {
        Validate.argumentIsNotNull(cdo);
        return this.baseJavaClass.isAssignableFrom(cdo.getClass());
    }
```

Javers has thrown **JaversExceptionCode.NOT_INSTANCE_OF** exception when I tried to modify an entity.

The error message is:

```
Can't create InstanceId for EntityType 'Objective', class 'com.project.domain.Objective' bounded to EntityType is not assignable from given class 'com.project.domain.Objective'
```

this.baseJavaClass is not assignable from cdo.getClass() , although both of them have the same name `Objective`.

This is a stack trace that I got: http://notepad.pw/j0z722vf

This error only occurs when I stop/start the app. But it's not occurring regularly. I don't know whether there is any caching in Javers. which we need to clear every time to restart the app.

Actually I cannot provide the test case which isolates the bug, because it's relating to the model mapping of the project. It also needs to create the Jhipster context to reproduce the bug. 
Then let me put the question here. I hope that there is someone who meets the similar issue.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to add full stack trace (not only the error message)  and also log level? What is the code you posted? Is it yours? Have you run under debugger to check the instance type? It could be because entity is wrapped in a proxy.

Comment: Actually there is another aspect is called when saving Objective object by its repository, I don't know this out has an effect on the Javers audit or not

Comment: and this is the log that I received:http://notepad.pw/j0z722vf

Comment: @GaëlMarziou thank you for your advice, I have edited the question. my pleasure if you're able to take a look.

Comment: I saw your issue on javers github https://github.com/javers/javers/issues/920 and I fully agree with Bartosz Walacik, the only way to progress is that you provide them with a runnable test case as stated in their guidelines. Your issue seems to be related to your project setup, so if you can't share your project, you should build a simpler project built without JHipster: a minimal spring boot jpa. Once you did that, it could help you to compare with real project or to build a runnable test using Spock.

Comment: thank you @GaëlMarziou, this ticket is created by me a few weeks ago, just because the error is not stable then I will wait until it occurs again, it means quite hard to reproduce it. Anyway, I will create a new project to reproduce the error on the separated project.

Comment: Alternatively you could compare your code with what is generated by https://github.com/hipster-labs/generator-jhipster-entity-audit on a simple project. Current version has some issues with JHipster 6 but I think it's only in frontend code.

Comment: Thank you too much @GaëlMarziou, I will double-check it

Comment: @HB did you had any follow up on this issue?

Comment: It looks like a "same class in different classloaders" issue, I had it once (probably after making a hotswap class change in debug), but after server restart, it disappeared.